# FTDI Device not detected

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, driver, ftdi

After connecting an FTDI device to the USB port, `FT_OpenEx()` returns an error code 2 which is `FT_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND`. However on running "lsusb" in the terminal, the FTDI device does show up. 
What is causing `FT_Open_Ex()` to return `FT_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND` if the device is listed by lsusb? What are the possible issues and solutions?

Output of lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:5776 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 Serial (UART) IC
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of dmesg | grep FTDI :

```
[28153.244220] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for FTDI USB Serial Device
[28153.244260] ftdi_sio 2-1:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[28153.244509] usb 2-1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

Output of dmesg | grep -i FTDI:

```
[28153.244206] usbcore: registered new interface driver ftdi_sio
[28153.244220] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for FTDI USB Serial Device
[28153.244260] ftdi_sio 2-1:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[28153.244509] usb 2-1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

Answer (score 3):

The dmesg output shows that ftdi_sio (a kernel module) has claimed the USB port to simulate a serial port.  This is the default behaviour for a typical Ubuntu installation.

FT_OpenEx is part of the FTDI D2XX API, which cannot access a device already claimed by ftdi_sio.

The [FTDI Linux D2XX notes](https://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX/Linux/ReadMe-linux.txt) suggest:

> ```
> sudo lsmod
> ```
>
> If "ftdi_sio" is listed:
> Unload it (and its helper module, usbserial), as follows.
>
> ```
> sudo rmmod ftdi_sio
> sudo rmmod usbserial
> ```

This will allow a D2XX program to access the device until the next reboot when the kernel will again load ftdi_sio.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58749607) gives one way to avoid having to manually unload it after every reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have read/write permissions on the device?
can you try
sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0

to make this permanent make a udev rule

create this file
/etc/udev/rules.d/99-ftdi.rules

> ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403",
> ATTRS={idProduct}=="6001"