# How to automatically run 'sudo modprobe -r ftdi_sio' whenever the device is plugged into my computer

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb, linux-device-driver

I have a USB device that I'm using and I'm developing an application using WebUSB with Google Chrome.
The thing is whenever I plug the USB  device into my Linux computer, I have to manually run `sudo modprobe -r ftdi_sio` to unload it.

I want it to be unloaded automatically whenever I plug that device into my computer instead of having to type it manually every single time.

Any ideas on how this could be implemented ? Help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to "blacklist" the ftdi_sio module to stop it being loaded automatically. To do that create the following file:

**/etc/modprobe.d/ftdi_sio-blacklist.conf**

```
# This is a comment. Change it if you want.
blacklist ftdi_sio
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your command in /etc/rc.local and restart. See if it works. Or you can find how other .ko are configured to automatically load during system startup. Follow the same to make your module load automatically.

Comment: First of all thank you for your reply !! This works when I restart my computer, not when I unplug-then-plug my device. I need this command to be initiated when I plug my device to my computer. Because every time I unplug my device I would have to run this command manually.

Comment: Or atleast in a way, to NEVER let Linux load this device for its own use.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way is to create a udev rule that is triggered when the specific USB device is attached.

Create a file /etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb-load.rules, and replace the "7523" and "1a86" with the Product ID and Vendor ID of your USB device.

```
# For debugging if the rule is working
ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="7523", ENV{ID_VENDOR}=="1a86", RUN+="/bin/sh -c '/bin/echo inserted device >> /tmp/udev_file'"
ACTION=="remove", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="7523", ENV{ID_VENDOR}=="1a86", RUN+="/bin/sh -c '/bin/echo removed device >> /tmp/udev_file'"

# Actual rules
ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="7523", ENV{ID_VENDOR}=="1a86", RUN+="/sbin/rmmod ftdi_sio"
ACTION=="remove", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="7523", ENV{ID_VENDOR}=="1a86", RUN+=""
```

Restart the udev daemon

```
sudo /etc/init.d/udev restart
```

The add rule will be executed whenever the USB device with matching PID/VID is attached and it will unload the module ftdi_sio. The first two rules are for debugging purposes which write a line into /tmp/udev_file and can be used to verify if the rules has been triggered.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'll try it out now

Comment: Did you get the logs in /tmp/udev_file? The first thing is to make sure that device triggers the rule correctly.

Comment: It might help if you could share some logs while adding the desired device. First the output of udevadm monitor --property and then udevadm monitor. Launch this command in one terminal and insert your device.

Comment: No unfortunately, I checked before commenting. I even tried putting those commands in the rule I had already created before, didn't work either. I even tried restarting my laptop but unfortunately didn't get anywhere. Thank you for help !!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like USB device is new and there are no existing drivers to handle as soon as it is plugged in. You need an interrupt line and a USB driver code for your requirement. You need to register your device to that driver and driver to the USB bus. Also need to write appropriate interrupt routines to be called as soon as your device is plugged in. This will make it work as you want !!

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a `.rules` file for the USB device then append the following to the pre-existing file in the `/etc/udev/rules.d/` directory. Otherwise, create a file in the `/etc/udev/rules.d/` directory with the following content:

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6010", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/sbin/rmmod ftdi_sio"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6010", ACTION=="remove", RUN+=""
```

This means that when the device with vendorID `0403` and product ID `6010` is plugged in it runs `/sbin/rmmod ftdi_sio` which removes the `ftdi_sio` module. The second rule means nothing will be run when unplugged. See [[writing udev rules]](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#builtin) for more info on how to name the `.rules` file (e.g. `99-mydevice.rules`)

You'll have to replace `0403` and `6010` with your device's vendor ID and prodcut ID. The vendor ID and product ID can be found by running `lsusb` on the command line after plugging in the USB device. It will have the format:

```
Bus xxx Device xxx: ID idVendor:idProduct ManufacturerName
```

After creating or editing the `.rules` file in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` directory be sure to reload the `.rules` file with the following command:

```
sudo udevadm control --reload
```

Some further references on udev rules:

[debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/udev)

[arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev)

[writing udev rules](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#builtin)